# Undefined Symbol: LoadExtern on Unity WebGL build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unresolved-external

I have a class **SaveSystem** which contains 2 extern methods: **SaveExtern, LoadExtern** these methods are supposed to be loaded externally from a lib in order to maintain cloud progress saving. But after this, Unity started to throw these errors on build. What may be the cause and how can I fix it.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8MNY.png)

```
Library\Bee\\artifacts\WebGL\build\debug_WebGL_wasm\build.js: undefined symbol:
LoadExtern (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAPHW.png)

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void SaveExtern(string data);
    
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void LoadExtern();
```

I tried reinstalling Unity, deleting everything from \Library, including **#if UNITY_WEBGL** and **#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WEBGL**

Comment: Please show your JS code .. sounds like `LoadExtern` is missing there / has a syntax error

Comment: The js code must be written in jslib after the build because jslib is actually created after build

Comment: It needs to exist **at the moment you build** the `jslib` needs to be existent and is then compiled together with the rest of your code into the web assembly ...

Comment: Well, maybe I understood something wrong, I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: Tysm bro, I really missed that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rather simple:

- You need to create a file **anyname.jslib** in folder **/Plugins** in your **/Assets** and implement methods you need inside this file.

You may find info about it here.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Big thanks to [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) for making up my mind